# Visual Studio Schema Compare

Tags: visual-studio, schema, sql-server-data-tools

I have two tables that are being compared using Schema Compare. What I don't understand is why a column is still highlighted as yellow or marked as being changed when it clearly hasn't been changed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I Think it is the order of columns that has changed, so the compare operation chooses to mark the remaining columns as modified. There is no AI-mechanism to interpret the order change of columns (DatabaseId moved to the end).

Comment: And along those lines, this will cause a table rebuilt - create temp table, populate from old, drop original table, re-create all PK/FK constraints, indexes, etc. Re-ordering columns in a table can have a huge impact on the database, especially for large tables.